# How to convert file.pvsm to file.vtk

Tags: vtk, paraview

Is there any way to convert `.pvsm` file (for ParaView) to `.vtk` file? I want to write a script that does that. It should work from command line in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that .pvsm are ParaView state files, so it does not contains the actual data but rather your pipeline analysis (reader, filters, rendering configuratation, etc...). See [the doc](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/savingResults.html#saving-state) for more.

Then, you can create ParaView python script that load a statefile and then add VTK writers on specific data from the pipeline.

#### minimal example

You have statefile "sample.pvsm" that load some data and apply filters. You want to write the output of "MyFilter"

```py
from paraview.simple import *
LoadState("sample.pvsm")
filter = FindSource("MyFilter")
SaveData("sample.vtk", filter)
```